# Why the decreasing the png/jpg quality factor in ImageIO.save() does not decrease the output image file size?

Tags: image, png, jpeg, codenameone

I have been using

```
ImageIO.getImageIO().save(image, os, ImageIO.FORMAT_PNG, qualityFactor)
```

method to save an Image in a file. Whatever float value between 0.0 and 1.0 I use as qualityFactor I always get the same output file size in kB, whatever format I choose (PNG or JPEG).

NB : I only checked this on the simulator (iPhone / Android) not on the real device.

What is the proper way for the qualityFactor to be taken into account ?

Cheers,

Comment: Ehmmm ... the qualityFactor (and others arguments) should be inside the `save()` method, no?

Comment: Well spotted @leonbloy, I edited my question, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hint to the underlying platform and not all platforms accept such a hint. iOS does but Android doesn't.

iOS only accepts it for JPEG so it will have no effect on PNG which is a lossless format.

Comment: OK, nice to know this! Thanks @Shai!

Answer (score 1):

There is no "Quality" adjustment in PNG. Apparently your encoder's API has such a setting for compatibility. In PNG, it is possible to do time vs. compression size but that does not affect the image quality.

In JPEG there are quality vs size trade offs. However, there is no "quality" factor that is inherent with JPEG. Quality is a function of subsampling, quantization table selection, and (to a small degree) optimal Huffman tables.

What your encoder is doing with the "quality" parameter is anyone's guess.